# find the sequence limit 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following sequence $(a_{n})$, $a_{1}=1$
$$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
a_{n}+\frac{1}{2} & \text{ if } n \ is \ even \\ 
\frac{a_{n}}{3} & \text{ if } n \ is \ odd 
\end{cases}$$
I need to find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{2n+1}$$

I tried something but I didn't get too far.I rewrite the sequence:$a_{1}=1$, $$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
a_{n}+r & \text{ if } n \ is \ even \\ 
q \cdot a_{n} & \text{ if } n \ is \ odd 
\end{cases}$$
where $q,r\in (0,1)$ but I don't know how to write $a_{2n+1}$ with $q$ and $r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine two steps in one: from one term with odd index, you have to divide by three to get the next term (with even index), then add 1/2 to get the next term with odd index.

This gives $b_n$, the series of terms with odd indices, i.e. $b_n = a_{2n+1}$, with $b_1 =1$,$b_{n+1} = \frac13 b_n + \frac12$. So 
$$
b_{n+1} =  \frac12 + \frac13 ( \frac12 + \frac13 ( \cdots (\frac12 + \frac13 b_1 ))\cdots)\\
=\frac12 (1 + \frac13 + (\frac13)^2+\cdots +(\frac13)^{n-1} )  + (\frac13)^{n} b_1\\
= \frac12 \frac{1 -(\frac13)^{n}}{2/3} + (\frac13)^{n} 
$$
so the limit is $\frac34$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!Why $b_{1}=1$ ? It shouldn't be $b_{1}=a_{3}=5/6$ ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I started erroneously with the index $n=0$. In any case, it makes no difference for the limit $n \to \infty$.

Comment: It took one day to understand the solution :).Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

We have, for each $n\in \Bbb N,$

$$a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}=\frac 12$$

thus
$(a_n)$ is not Cauchy.

What can you conclude ?

Comment: What does this say  about   $a_{2n} - a_{2n-1}$?

Comment: It is $\frac{-2}{3}a_{2n-1}$.